# Kibana connection is refused while connecting through CURL?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04, kibana, connection-refused

I have install elasticsearch and kibana in the **Google VM instance** (**Ubuntu-16.04**) and configured them respectively. I have check the status of elasticsearch and kibana. Both are in active (running state).

I have viewed elasticsearch usingcommand,
 **curl -XGET "{ip-addr}:9200"**. The output is

```
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster-1",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When I'm trying to see for kibana with **curl -XGET "{ip-addr}:5601"**, it is throwing error as

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  {ip-addr} port 5601: Connection refused
```

The changes I have done in **kibana.yml** file  are :

```
server.port: 5601 
server.host: 10.128.0.2 
server.name: "tserver" 
elasticsearch.url: "10.128.0.2:9200" 
kibana.index: ".tkibana" 
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log
```

The log file is also not updating.

When kibana is in active state, I'm trying this command **curl -XGET "10.128.0.2:5601"** , the status of kibana is going to be inactive.

I found this port is not listened. I have checked the 9200 and 5601 ports using following commands.

**netstat -a -n | grep tcp | grep 9200** , the output is
 **tcp6       0      0 10.128.0.2:9200         :::*                    LISTEN**

But for 5601 port, **netstat -a -n | grep tcp | grep 5601** , the output is null (empty message).

I have to view elasticsearch data in kibana console, So should I install Loagstash too  or not needed ???

Can, anybody help me out from this problem.

Comment: something is blocking port 5601, but not port 9200.. firewall probably?

Answer (score 1):

In your `kibana.yml` file, you need to modify the following setting in order for Kibana to bind to the proper interface:

```
server.host: 10.128.0.2
```

Much like you did in `elasticsearch.yml` for Elasticsearch

Comment: I have done like that only @Val , but it is not working.

Comment: What does the log of Kibana tell us?

Comment: I didn't get any change in log file. I noticed nothing added to log file. @Val

Comment: Ok, but can you share what's in it?

Comment: I have changed the kibana.yml file. The changes I have done are : server.port: 5601 server.host: 10.128.0.2 server.name: "tserver" elasticsearch.url: "10.128.0.2:9200" kibana.index: ".tkibana" logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log

Comment: And does it work now? if not, can you provide the content of `/var/log/kibana/kibana.log`

Comment: the kibana.log file is empty @Val . So, what I can do ? I have also include the changes in kibana.yml file. So, can you check and say if I need to change some more changes in that file.

Comment: Have you restarted Kibana after changing the file? If yes, can you show the logs you get in the console?

Comment: the status of kibana is as follows ● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-09-08 06:51:02 UTC; 196ms ago
 Main PID: 3548 (node)
    Tasks: 6
   Memory: 16.0M
      CPU: 208ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─3548 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

Sep 08 06:51:02 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.

Comment: When I try to connect using curl -XGET "10.128.0.2:5601" , it is throwing error ,curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.128.0.2 port 5601: Connection refused . and Now, the status is changed to inactive state.

Comment: Update your question with the logs, it is not legible in comments

Comment: When I'm listening to port 9200, netstat -a -n | grep tcp | grep 9200 . The output is tcp6       0      0 10.128.0.2:9200         :::*                    LISTEN     
But, when I'm trying to listen 5601 port, netstat -a -n | grep tcp | grep 5601 , it is showing nothing (empty message). Can please, help me out from this issue.

Comment: Read my last comment please

Comment: I have updated the question @Val , please go through it once.

Comment: All this means that kibana is not starting... What do you see in your console when you run `bin/kibana` ? That's all I'm asking

Comment: I'm using Google VM instance (Ubuntu 16.04) . I'm not able to see console in it. But I'm using  sudo service kibana start for starting kibana. So, how to see the console.

Comment: And the reason why it doesn't work is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115504/kibana-is-not-starting-working/46115788#46115788 . This question is solved then :-)