# Kibana is not starting / working?

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04, kibana

I have installed and configured kibana in Ubuntu 16.04 (**VM Instance**). When I'm running the bin file, kibana is not starting. The log file is having error message as follows. 
"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:kibana@5.2.2","info"],"pid":7300,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green -

```
Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.2","info"],"pid":7300,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:console@5.2.2","info"],"pid":7300,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.2","error"],"pid":7300,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v5.2.2 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v2.3.1 @ 10.128.0.2:9200 (10.128.0.2)","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:timelion@5.2.2","info"],"pid":7300,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":7300,"message":"Server running at http://10.128.0.2:5601"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-09-08T11:21:53Z","tags":["status","ui settings","error"],"pid":7300,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Elasticsearch plugin is red","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
```

Can, anyone help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is stated in the log:

> This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v5.2.2 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v2.3.1

This means that you have installed Kibana 5.2.2 but your ES server version is 2.3.1. You need to install ES 5.2.2 for this to work.